# Does any one have the archive node data?

Tags: database

I want to analyze the archive node data in geth, but the sync seems slow, is there any archive node data? node data with a very lower height will be ok.I just want to run the cmd 'geth db inspect' in archive node.

Comment: In case people want a node to gather the data or more creative things, there are currently grants for running a node: https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/743/did-you-know-theres-grants-for-running-an-ethereum-node

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you are trying to do with the data, but you can use something like [infura](https://infura.io) or [alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) to access archive node data if you don't mind using their service.

Comment: I just want to exec the command 'geth db inspect' to find which part takes the most storage space in archive node